# Selenium Python Authenticating issue

Tags: python, selenium

To open in Selenium a page where authentication is needed the code below is appropriate.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://username:password@testwebsite.com/testpage.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

But the above works when a page should be open directly from Selenium as the initial page.

In my project, I click a link that opens a page where an authentication as above is required.

How to resolve it? I can not use directly driver.get(...) because I can not open directly this page...

Comment: Hi, could you clarify your question? Which page is it that you can't open directly?

Comment: Using Selenium imagine the path:                                                                                                   open www.example.com  - autentication is needed (the solution above works)                                                                       click Login type -.a login page is going to open, and the authentication is required again This time the solution above doesn't work.